# Tikz 3D Plot: Plane that cuts through a cube

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I would like to draw a cube that intersects with the plane [image] while highlighting the intersected area. What I have accomplished so far is the plot below. Unfortunately, the plane looks like being in front of the cube. What I would like to have instead is the cut corner being in front of the plane.

Thanks much for your help.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,perspective}
%
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={120}{15},line join=round,
        declare function={a=4;b=2;}]
        \draw[style=dashed, color=black] (a,0,-a) -- (0,0,-a)-- (0,a,-a);
        \draw[style=dashed, color=black] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,-a); 
        \draw[thick,black] (a,0,0) -- (a,0,-a) -- (a,a,-a) -- (a,a,-b);
        \draw[thick,black] (a,a-b,0) -- (a,0,0) -- (0,0,0) -- (0,a,0) -- (a-b,a,0);
        \draw[thick,black] (0,a,0) -- (0,a,-a) -- (a,a,-a);
        \draw[thick,black] (a-b,a,0) -- (a,a,0) -- (a,a-b,0);
        \draw[thick,black] (a,a,0) -- (a,a,-b); 
        \draw[thick,pattern=north east lines] (a,a,-b) -- (a-b,a,0) -- (a,a-b,0) -- cycle;
        \fill[gray,opacity=0.2] (4,0.5,1.5) -- (0.5,4,1.5) -- (2.75,6.25,-3) -- (6.25,2.75,-3) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}%
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cooked a little something up for you:

[image]

This is achieved by using clipping paths inside a scope, like this:

```latex
\begin{scope}
    \clip
        (4,0.5,1.5) -- (0.5,4,1.5) -- (2.75,6.25,-3) -- (6.25,2.75,-3) -- cycle % the plane
        (a,a,-b) -- (a-b,a,0) -- (a,a-b,0) -- cycle; % the triangle cutout 
    \draw[fill=blue, draw=none, opacity=0.5] (4,0.5,1.5) -- (0.5,4,1.5) -- (2.75,6.25,-3) -- (6.25,2.75,-3) -- cycle; 
\end{scope}
```

In `\clip` you define the clipping mask for the scope, by subtracting the triangle from the plane. Then you fill/draw the whole plane area with `\draw`, which is then drawn on the clipping mask.

The whole code:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={200}{15},line join=round, thick,
        declare function={a=4;b=2;}]
        
        % the cube edges
        \draw[dashed] (a,0,-a) -- (0,0,-a)-- (0,a,-a);
        \draw[dashed] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,-a); 
        \draw (a,0,0) -- (a,0,-a) -- (a,a,-a) -- (a,a,-b);
        \draw (a,a-b,0) -- (a,0,0) -- (0,0,0) -- (0,a,0) -- (a-b,a,0);
        \draw (0,a,0) -- (0,a,-a) -- (a,a,-a);
        \draw (a-b,a,0) -- (a,a,0) -- (a,a-b,0);
        \draw (a,a,0) -- (a,a,-b); 
        
        % the cube/plane cross-section surface
%       \draw[fill=white, fill opacity=0.2, draw opacity=0.8] (a,a,-b) -- (a-b,a,0) -- (a,a-b,0) -- cycle;
            
        % the plane
        \begin{scope}
            \clip
            (4,0.5,1.5) -- (0.5,4,1.5) -- (2.75,6.25,-3) -- (6.25,2.75,-3) -- cycle % the plane
            (a,a,-b) -- (a-b,a,0) -- (a,a-b,0) -- cycle; % cutout A (cross section)
%           (a,a,0) -- (a,a,-b) -- (a-b,a,0) -- (a,a-b,0) -- cycle; % cutout B (cube corner)
            \draw[fill=blue, draw=none, opacity=0.5] (4,0.5,1.5) -- (0.5,4,1.5) -- (2.75,6.25,-3) -- (6.25,2.75,-3) -- cycle;
        \end{scope}
        
%        % the cube corner surface        
%       \draw[fill=white, opacity=0.8] (a,a,0) -- (a,a,-b) -- (a-b,a,0) -- (a,a-b,0) -- cycle;

        % the cube corner edges
        \draw (a,a,0) -- (a,a,-b) (a,a,0) -- (a-b,a,0) (a,a,0) -- (a,a-b,0); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see I left some lines commented out; these are some optional modifications for you to experiment around with. You could comment out "cutout A" and use "cutout B" instead. Or/and if you intend to fill the cube corner with a solid color, uncomment the line where the cube corner surface is drawn.

And lastly, I added some structure and comments to the code. I'm mentioning this, because if you plan on using TikZ more extensively in the future, you're doing yourself a big favor if you get used to structuring and labeling your components in the code early on.

Answer (score 2):

You can draw the corner after the plane, so that it is not obscured.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,perspective}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={120}{15},line join=round, thick,
        declare function={a=4;b=2;}]
        \draw[dashed] (a,0,-a) -- (0,0,-a)-- (0,a,-a);
        \draw[dashed] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,-a); 
        \draw (a,0,0) -- (a,0,-a) -- (a,a,-a) -- (a,a,-b);
        \draw (a,a-b,0) -- (a,0,0) -- (0,0,0) -- (0,a,0) -- (a-b,a,0);
        \draw (0,a,0) -- (0,a,-a) -- (a,a,-a);
        \draw (a-b,a,0) -- (a,a,0) -- (a,a-b,0);
        \draw (a,a,0) -- (a,a,-b); 
        \fill[lightgray, opacity=0.8] (4,0.5,1.5) -- (0.5,4,1.5) -- (2.75,6.25,-3) -- (6.25,2.75,-3) -- cycle;
        \draw[pattern=north east lines] (a,a,-b) -- (a-b,a,0) -- (a,a-b,0) -- cycle;
        \draw (a,a,0) -- (a,a,-b) (a,a,0) -- (a-b,a,0) (a,a,0) -- (a,a-b,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Cube with plane cutting corner]

Comment: Thanks much for the comment. I appreciate your help. The solution is pretty easy in the end :-). Please see my comment to the answer of @d8xa.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @hpekristiansen's answer you could draw a translucent white background behind the pattern to make it stand out from the plane. Just add `preaction={fill=white, opacity=0.8}` to `pattern=north east lines`:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,perspective}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={120}{15},line join=round, thick,
        declare function={a=4;b=2;}]
        \draw[dashed] (a,0,-a) -- (0,0,-a)-- (0,a,-a);
        \draw[dashed] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,-a); 
        \draw (a,0,0) -- (a,0,-a) -- (a,a,-a) -- (a,a,-b);
        \draw (a,a-b,0) -- (a,0,0) -- (0,0,0) -- (0,a,0) -- (a-b,a,0);
        \draw (0,a,0) -- (0,a,-a) -- (a,a,-a);
        \draw (a-b,a,0) -- (a,a,0) -- (a,a-b,0);
        \draw (a,a,0) -- (a,a,-b); 
        \fill[lightgray, opacity=0.8] (4,0.5,1.5) -- (0.5,4,1.5) -- (2.75,6.25,-3) -- (6.25,2.75,-3) -- cycle;
        \draw[pattern=north east lines, preaction={fill=white, opacity=0.8}] (a,a,-b) -- (a-b,a,0) -- (a,a-b,0) -- cycle;
        \draw (a,a,0) -- (a,a,-b) (a,a,0) -- (a-b,a,0) (a,a,0) -- (a,a-b,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks much for the comment. This is what I was looking for. Pretty simple in the end :-). However, I was just curious of what would happen when changing the view from let's say120 to 200 (forget about the dashed lines then). In this perspective the plane shines through the facet of the cube. Can this be easily fixed as well?

Comment: @VK88 I posted a second answer which solves this problem generally for any viewing angle, and which is more customizable. You might want to accept that one instead.